AppScript script to convert date format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy
So, i'm trying to automate my work, i'm new to javascript and i'm trying to introduce it in my routine, i've come with a problem, the sheets came w dates in mm/dd/yyyy format and i want to make a script to change it to dd/mm/yyyy format
I've tried to create a script function, it is:
Basically i'm trying to change the date format of the j2 and L interval
function convertColumns() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("J2:L10000");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var newValues = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    newValues.push([row[0], row[1], row[2].replace(/\//g, "-")]);
  }
  range.setValues(newValues);
}



date = date.replace(/^(.)\/(.)\/(.)$/, '$2/$1/$3'); assuming all dates are mm/dd/yyyy

But where do it change or where do i put that?

Where are the dates? In row[2]. if yes, why are you changing / to - when you tell use you want dd/mm/yyyy - if that is the datestring, then row[2] = row[2].replace(/^(.)\/(.)\/(.)$/, '$2/$1/$3') If more than one date in the same string, we need to do something else. Please read [mcve]

If your value is a data object all you need to do is setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
